# DataSet in Presentation Layer

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, dataset

I am making `asp.net` site using Layered architecture. Can I implement and use `Data-Set` object in presentation layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simple layered architecture might have:

Datasets being populated in the DAL

Business Entities / Domain objects in the 'BLL' are populated from the DAL Datasets

The presentation objects are pretty simple data transfer objects that match whatever is being presented.

Obviously there is a bit more to it than this.

Pluralsight have just [released a course](http://blog.pluralsight.com/2012/08/03/video-peeling-the-onion-architecture-of-an-n-tier-application/) that might be worth your time?

Answer (score 0):

Data Access Layer and Business Logic Layer is better place for it. To get more insight try [Creating a DAL](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/introduction/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs) and [Creating a BLL](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/introduction/creating-a-business-logic-layer-cs).

Obviously You can use it, but layered architecture is all about separating layers.

Answer (score 0):

For interacting with database, you should use Data Access Layer.

You can have a look the aim of data access layer.

[What is the purpose of a Data Access Layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59942/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-data-access-layer)